# Instanceof inconsistency

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain the following?

```
[] instanceof Array; // true
'' instanceof String; // false
```

Comment: Also `typeof ""` is `"string"` and `typeof []` is `"object"` (you'd expect `"array"` but alright I can live with that)

Comment: Guessing, could the '' be a primitive, but [] an object?

Comment: +1 Interesting, because `"".constructor === String`.

Comment: ... though the specs confirm this behaviour: "If V is not an object, return false." (15.3.5.3)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note the following:

```
"" instanceof String;             // => false
new String("") instanceof String; // => true
```

[`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) requires an object, but `""` is a string literal, and not a String object.  Note the following types using the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) function:

```
typeof ""             // => "string"
typeof new String("") // => "object"
typeof []             // => "object"
typeof new Array()    // => "object"
```

Comment: What then is the difference between a `literal string` and `String` object and why is it (apparently) important? As far as I know they can be used interchangeably but the result is that you can't use `instanceof` to check whether something is a 'string'

Comment: But isn't `[]` an array literal in the same way that `''` is a string literal?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo array can contain all kinds of primitives and objects.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: That's about it. You can use them interchangeably but `instanceof` will return a different value. JavaScript the most pretty consistent language is not.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo No.  `instanceof` only works on objects, which "" is not.  `typeof "" // => "string"`; `typeof new String("") // => "object"`; `typeof [] // => "object"`; `typeof new Array() // => "object".`

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Only numbers, strings and booleans can be primitives.

Comment: @lonesomeday primitives != literals. There are also the null literal and regex literals.

Answer (score 11):

It's because `''` is primitive, not an object.

Some primitives in JavaScript can have an object wrapper. These are created when you make an *instance* of the wrapper using the built in constructor with `new`.

The `new` is typically necessary because often times the function will coerce to a primitive if you exclude `new`.

```
typeof new String('');  // "object"
typeof String('');      // "string"
typeof '';              // "string"
```

The primitives that have Object wrappers are `string`, `number` and `boolean`.

The primitives that do not are `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: So what is the primitive (i.e. non-wrapper object) of `[]`?

Comment: Randomblue: There isn't one. An Array is always an Object.

Comment: @Randomblue doesn't exist. Why would there be a primitive?

Comment: @Raynos: I tried, but StackOverflow won't let me make it any longer.

Answer (score 3):

`''` isn't an instance of anything; it's a primitive type, and it works in much the same way as `5.5` or `true`. There's a difference between a string primitive and a String object. See:

```
new String('') instanceof String; // true
```

Anything created with `new String()`, `new Number()` or `new Boolean()` is an object wrapper around the primitive type, and they're not the same.

To check for strings, etc., use `typeof` instead:

```
typeof '' === 'string'; // true
```

To check for *both*, use this:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call('') === '[object String]'; // true
Object.prototype.toString.call(new String('')) === '[object String]'; // true
```

There are a couple of reasons to use `Object.prototype.toString.call` for general-use code, for arrays, strings, numbers *and* booleans. They are:

1. For strings, numbers, and booleans, people may pass instances of the wrapper objects instead of the primitive types. They usually function in the same way (with an implicit `valueOf()`) and so you should accept them if writing library code.
2. For arrays, if you receive an array *from another window* (say from an `<iframe>`) then using `instanceof Array` will return `false`. The `Object.prototype.toString.call` method works for all purposes.

This is what jQuery and other large, popular libraries do.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some digging and I suppose it has to do with [**string interning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) which is a compiler optimization.

Okay, ready for some gotchas? :D

```
"abc" == "abc"; // true
"abc" === "abc"; // true
```

I suppose this is true because of "string interning" which coincidentally also makes a lot of sense, conceptually (yay for getting 'strings' right).

```
new String("abc") == new String("abc"); // false
new String("abc") === new String("abc");    // false
```

This makes sense if you assume a `String` is an object and an object is only equal to itself and not equal to object with similar internal state. Like in Java (or how it used to be anyway).

And now for the kicker:

```
(new String("abc")).substr(0,3) === (new String("abc")).substr(0,3); // true!
```

So apparently the JavaScript interpreter will always prefer string interning over the use of the `String` object.

Then I must ask, what is the use of the `String` object? Apparently it doesn't play nice with its friends.

Comment: The first one, `"abc" === "abc"`, isn't because of string interning. Strict equality works as you'd expect for primitive types. `===` is only "reference-equals" for objects.

Comment: The String `type` is only there to allow you to extend its prototype and also to allow you to create `Objects`-like strings. That is objects  (similar to pointers in C) will only be `===` if they are `same pointer`